# Inkscape Cut out

Tags: inkscape

I have two objects, a heart and a t-shirt, that I'd like use.  I'd like to place the t-shirt over the heart and cut out that section of the heart like this:

[image]

However, when I try to use the difference command, my heart changes shape:

[image]

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  My bezier tool was set to spiro when I drew the heart.  Is that affecting it?

Answer (score 3):

> I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. My bezier tool was set to spiro when I drew the heart. Is that affecting it?

That’s extremely likely. I would suspect that *difference* was not programmed to take spiros into account and treated your path like a regular Bézier curve (though it wasn’t).

Just selecet your heart and apply *object to path* before applying *difference,* and everything should work as expected.